# SELECT statement optimization MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, query-optimization

I am looking for a way how to make my SELECT query even faster than it is now, because I have a feeling it should be possible to make it faster.

Here is the query

```
SELECT r.id_customer, ROUND(AVG(tp.percentile_weighted), 2) AS percentile
FROM tag_rating AS r USE INDEX (value_date_add)
JOIN tag_product AS tp ON (tp.id_pair = r.id_pair)
WHERE 
r.value = 1 AND
r.date_add > '2020-08-08 11:56:00'
GROUP BY r.id_customer
```

Here is EXPLAIN SELECT

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------+----------------+---------+---------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys  | key            | key_len | ref           | rows   | Extra                                                               |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------+----------------+---------+---------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | SIMPLE      | r     | ref    | value_date_add | value_date_add | 1       | const         | 449502 | Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------+----------------+---------+---------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | SIMPLE      | tp    | eq_ref | PRIMARY        | PRIMARY        | 4       | dev.r.id_pair | 1      |                                                                     |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------+----------------+---------+---------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now the tables are

```
CREATE TABLE `tag_product` (
  `id_pair` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_product` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_user_tag` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(3) NOT NULL,
  `percentile` decimal(8,4) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `percentile_weighted` decimal(8,4) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `elo` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date_add` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_upd` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_pair`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_product_id_user_tag` (`id_product`,`id_user_tag`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `id_user_tag` (`id_user_tag`),
  CONSTRAINT `tag_product_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`id_user_tag`) REFERENCES `user_tag` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
CREATE TABLE `tag_rating` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_customer` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_pair` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_duel` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `value` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `date_add` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_duel_id_pair` (`id_duel`,`id_pair`),
  KEY `id_pair_id_customer` (`id_pair`,`id_customer`),
  KEY `value` (`value`),
  KEY `value_date_add` (`value`,`date_add`),
  KEY `id_customer_value_date_add` (`id_customer`,`value`,`date_add`),
  CONSTRAINT `tag_rating_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`id_pair`) REFERENCES `tag_product` (`id_pair`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `tag_rating_ibfk_6` FOREIGN KEY (`id_duel`) REFERENCES `tag_rating_duel` (`id_duel`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

The table tag_product has about 250k rows and the tag_rating has about 1M rows.

My issue is that the SQL query takes about 0.8s on average on my machine. I would like to make it ideally under 0.5s while also assuming the tables can get like 10 times bigger. The amount of rows taken into play should be about the same because I have a date condition (I only want less than a month old rows).

Is this possible to make faster just by some trick (aka not restructuring my tables)? When I slightly modify (dont join the smaller table) the statement as

```
SELECT r.id_customer, COUNT(*)
FROM tag_rating AS r USE INDEX (value_date_add)
WHERE 
r.value = 1 AND
r.date_add > '2020-08-08 11:56:00'
GROUP BY r.id_customer;
```

here is EXPLAIN SELECT

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+----------------+----------------+---------+-------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys  | key            | key_len | ref   | rows   | Extra                                                               |
+----+-------------+-------+------+----------------+----------------+---------+-------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | SIMPLE      | r     | ref  | value_date_add | value_date_add | 1       | const | 449502 | Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+------+----------------+----------------+---------+-------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

it takes about 0.25s which is great. So the JOIN makes it 3x slower. Is that inevitable? I feel like since I am joining via primary key it shouldnt make a query 3x slower.

---UPDATE---

This is actually my query. The number of different id_customer values is about 1 thousand and is expected to rise, the number of rows with value=1 is exactly half. So far the query performance seems to be slowing down linearly based on the number of rows in rating table

Using adding id_pair at the end of the id_customer_value_date_add or value_id_customer_date_add index doesnt help.

```
SELECT r.id_customer, ROUND(AVG(tp.percentile_weighted), 2) AS percentile
FROM tag_rating AS r USE INDEX (id_customer_value_date_add)
JOIN tag_product AS tp ON (tp.id_pair = r.id_pair)
WHERE 
r.value = 1 AND
r.id_customer IN (2593179,1461878,2318871,2654090,2840415,2852531,2987432,3473275,3960453,3961798,4129734,4191571,4202912,4204817,4211263,4248789,765650,1341317,1430380,2116196,3367674,3701901,3995273,4118307,4136114,4236589,783262,913493,1034296,2626574,3574634,3785772,2825128,4157953,3331279,4180367,4208685,4287879,1038898,1445750,1975108,3658055,4185296,4276189,428693,4248631,1892448,3773855,2901524,3830868,3934786) AND
r.date_add > '2020-08-08 11:56:00'
GROUP BY r.id_customer
```

This is EXPLAIN SELECT

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------+----------------------------------+--------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys              | key                        | key_len | ref                              | rows   | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------+----------------------------------+--------+--------------------------+
| 1  | SIMPLE      | r     | range  | id_customer_value_date_add | id_customer_value_date_add | 10      |                                  | 558906 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------+----------------------------------+--------+--------------------------+
| 1  | SIMPLE      | tp    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,status             | PRIMARY                    | 4       | dev.r.id_pair | 1      | Using where              |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------+----------------------------------+--------+--------------------------+
```

Any tips are appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
INDEX(value, date_add, id_customer, id_pair)
```

Would be "covering", giving an extra boost on performance for both queries.  And also for Gordon's formulation.

At the same time, get rid of these:

```
KEY `value` (`value`),
KEY `value_date_add` (`value`,`date_add`),
```

because they might get in the way of the Optimizer picking the new index.  Any other queries that were using those indexes will easily use the new index.

If you are not otherwise using `tag_rating.id`, get rid of it and promote the `UNIQUE` to `PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: thank you. adding the index made the query like 20% faster. I also tried getting rid of the id column as you suggested and it made a bigger difference when used with my previous index. The only thing I dont understand is why it became faster just by removing a column (I didnt even have to create a primary index and it was already faster).
I should also mention that in reality I also have a where condition on r.id_customer IN (like 100 ids) and the index is also extended to match this. but the query was still slow so i ommited it to make the question simpler

Comment: Making the query simpler leads to making it different, and us to advise you on the simpler query.  Any change to a query, _even a minor change_, may invalidate the advice that worked well for the 'simpler' query.  If you want advice on the `IN`, please provide that query.

Comment: @honzaik - And if I understand your correction, this may help:  `INDEX(value, id_customer, date_add, id_pair)` -- giving the Optimizer another index to consider.

Comment: sorry for the delay, I have updated the question. Adding the id_pair to the end of the index doesnt seem to do anything as explain says the key_len used is the same with or without it. So far the query time is growing linearly with the amount of rows inside tag_rating table (actually the tag_product and tag_rating grow at the same rate - for every added tag_product row there is 5 rows added to tag_rating)

Comment: @honzaik - `EXPLAIN` does not show that in `key_len`.  It does show that the index is "covering" by saying (in the `Extra` column) `Using index`.  The benefit of "covering" is that it only has to look at the index's BTree, without also touching the data's BTree.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing the query using a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT r.id_customer,
       (SELECT ROUND(AVG(tp.percentile_weighted), 2)
        FROM tag_product tp 
        WHERE tp.id_pair = r.id_pair
       ) AS percentile
FROM tag_rating AS r 
WHERE r.value = 1 AND
      r.date_add > '2020-08-08 11:56:00';
```

This eliminates the outer aggregation which should be faster.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. My query calculates average of percentile_weighted from selected rows from tag_product for every id_customer. your query doesnt group. Am I missing something?

Comment: @honzaik . . . It has a correlated subquery, so it is only calculating the average when the pairs match.

Comment: but your query returns the number of rows that r.value && r.date_add match. my query returns "number of unique id_customers" rows. they are not the same. the number of unique users is a few hundreds. the number of rows in rating is hundreds of thousands